Google sheet function to extract values based on nested conditions. (Complex)
I am trying to solve for a problem. I have a name range and a condition range.



Name
Yes/No




First
row


Second
row



I have a master data sheet containing various values associated with different names. I aim to display these values in a new column only if a corresponding 'Yes/No' indicator for each name is set to 'Yes'. For instance, if the 'Yes/No' indicator for the name 'X' is set to 'Yes' for all associated values, I intend to exhibit these values from the master data in a new column (Column 3).
However, in my current approach, which involves utilizing the IF and QUERY functions, I encounter an issue where the execution of the first condition seems to prevent the evaluation of subsequent conditions. How can I ensure that all conditions are properly assessed?
Can you help me find a solution to this issue.
Any help would be appreciated.
This is the link to the sheet and my failed attempts at it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iB8_4-yTzM1HgdS8skE1Ce0nunoRU6F0rUq4WVzkO2E/edit#gid=0


Here's one approach you may test out:
=reduce({D2:E2,"Data Correct"},unique(tocol(D3:D13,1)),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,hstack(filter(D3:E13,D3:D13=c),if(countifs(D3:D13,c,E3:E13,"<>y")=0,filter('Master Data'!A:A,'Master Data'!B:B=c),))))))



Sheet TRY F3 (Data Correct) =
=(IF(AND(B3=INDEX('Master Data'!$B$1:$B$12, ROW()-1), C3="Y"), INDEX('Master Data'!$A$1:$A$12, ROW()-1), ""))

